# Bing location names for different markets

Tags: c#, bing-maps

I am trying to load Bing map in my c# web browser control and get the location names for different markets like London en-US same for Londers in fr-FR. But I am unable to change market tried with REST service as well any solution would be appreciated

Comment: Sharing your code would be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you are using the Bing Maps v7 AJAX control in the web browser control. To set the culture you need to specify it in the script reference to the Bing Maps control when loading the page. You can find documentation on this here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427600.aspx

That said, if you are working with Bing Maps in .NET why not use the Bing Maps WPF control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750210.aspx